# SLURM how to know if a running job is a srun or a sbatch job?

Tags: slurm

I need to distinguish between batch and interactive job when are in RUNNING state.
I can't find  with `sact` or `stat` a way to know if a job is a interactive session.

Did anyone already solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `batchflag` formatting keyword in the `squeue` command to infer if a job has been submitted using the sbatch command.

```
$ squeue --Format=batchflag -u ${USER} --states=RUNNING
```

From the BatchFlag description in the `scontrol` [help page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html):

> Jobs submitted using the sbatch command have BatchFlag set to 1. Jobs submitted using other commands have BatchFlag set to 0.